# Custom brush stroke android: Black color border around custom shape

Tags: android

I am trying to make a custom brush. I took an image and trying it draw it on canvas when i touch and move the finger. I have a star shape png image with only white color. I planned to change the color according to color selection by user. To change the color I am using color matrix as follows :

```
    float[] colorTransform = { //For red color as of now
            1f,0 , 0, 0,0, 
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
            0, 0, 0, 1, 0};

    ColorMatrix colorMatrix = new ColorMatrix();
   // colorMatrix.setSaturation(0f); //Remove Colour 
    colorMatrix.set(colorTransform); //Apply the Red

    ColorMatrixColorFilter colorFilter = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(colorMatrix);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColorFilter(colorFilter);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);

    for (Point pos: positions)
    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmapBrush, pos.x, pos.y, paint);
```

Everything seems to work fine with one problem: 
"While drawing Bitmap I am getting a thin black color border around my star shape". Am I using colormatrix in wrong way ? Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you maybe include the bitmap that you are trying to draw? This could help figuring out why the thin border appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the color matrix to *replace* the original color of the bitmap, change the right-most column.

```
float[] colorTransform = { 
        0, 0, 0, 0, 255, // Set red component of each output pixel to max
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
        0, 0, 0, 1, 0};  // Copy over the alpha channel from the input
```

The last column is an offset term. It is added to the result, no matter how the input looked like. In above example, 255 is added to the red channel.

Note that the top-left 3x4 submatrix is empty. This essentially discards all color information in the input image. The 5th column adds color again: the color that the user picked.

Comment: Thanks. It worked . I am still confused that why my approach didnt work. The matrix I provided should make all components zero except red one. So If my .png image only has white , it should make it red . isnt it ?

Comment: Glad that it worked. It would be easier for us to debug your initial solution if you would attach the bitmap image.

Please feel free to mark the answer as accepted. Accepting correct answers signals to other SO users with a similar problem that the answer solves the problem, and also yields reputation to the user who answered.